# Conditionally remove the space before a one-letter operator

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators

I'm pursuing the Math Expectation operator (`\mathbb{E}`).

As `\DeclareMathOperator` is not very good for one-letter operators (since it adds some spacing after itself), I use a plain `\newcommand`. But here comes the problem that there's no space *before* it, so writing something like `X \MyExpct X` turns into something without spaces, while I would like to see a space between the first `X` and `\MyExpct`.

But adding a spacing into `\newcommand` before `\mathbb{E}`, like

```
\newcommand{\MyExpct}{\,\mathbb{E}}
```

fails when my operator stand in the beginning of an expression! So what I want is a space which would be added before the operator if something (but not a binary operation or a opening bracket!) stands before it, and which would be removed otherwise.

I tried to play with `\unskip`, `\ignorespaces`, and even looked into how `\DeclareMathOperator` deals with it (via `\kern`) but failed to find the solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Math operators are expected to have a thin space after them, if not followed by a parenthesis or other delimiter. I don't know why you wouldn't want it, but `\newcommand{\MyExpct}{\mathop{}\!\mathbb{E}}` should do.

Comment: Thanks @egreg! Yes, since expectation is a sort of an operator which doesn't look neat when it doesn't have parenthesis, I wanted to remove this space. In other words, to "visually attach" the argument to the E-symbol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rule for a math operator is that in case it's preceded/followed by an ordinary symbol, then a thin space is inserted. This is what's wanted in cases such as

```
$a\log b$
```

where we *do* want a thin space before and after “log”. In a case such as

```
$a\log(bc)$
```

the space is inserted only before “log”.

I don't know why you don't want your operator to behave differently; perhaps you don't want to add parentheses and trust on the different shape of the letter for visual distinction. So here's the way:

```
\newcommand{\MExp}{\mathop{}\!\mathbb{E}}
```

If `\MExp` is preceded by an ordinary operator, the thin space will be inserted. However, since the empty `\mathop` is followed by an ordinary symbol, it would *always* insert a thin space, that we remove with `\!`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\MExp}{\mathop{}\!\mathbb{E}}

\begin{document}
X$\MExp$ has no space

$X \MExp X$ shows space and no space
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not a fan of the syntax, but I've seen it before as in XS for the "closure" or "pointed" version of S. But then again is X then really an operator? In the OPs case a bit more information might be in order

Comment: Thanks! Yes, exactly, I wanted to work with expectation also without parentheses. In this case the space makes it a bit visually detached from its argument.

Comment: "I don't know why you don't want your operator to behave differently" This is helful to write the differential df of functions. I don't want space between the d and the f and on the other hand, but when I take the composition with e.g. the determinant, I want space between the circle and the d. Hence, your answer helped a lot.