# Two letter variables with upright Delta

Tags: fonts, math-mode, spacing, typography, greek

I'm using `newtxmath` with the `slanted` and `libertine` option in order to get standard slanted greek letters in mathmode as well as the option for upright greek letters.

My question concerns a common two letter variable consisting of a captial Delta and a variable (either latin or greek). It is used in physics to denote the finite increase of a quantity (cf. IUPAP Red Book, Sec. 5.2). The problem when simply typing `\upDelta x` it can lead to results that look confusing:

[image: Meaning of expression unclear]

The Problem is that the spacing between all symbols is equal and it is not clear that the Delta belongs to the following variable.

My attempt now is to remove the space after the Delta that denotes hidden multiplication. In the accepted answer to a similar question ([Two letter variable names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6087/two-letter-variable-names)) the use  of `\mathit{}` was recommended:

```
\mathit{NA} \neq NA = N \cdot A
```

[image]

This, however, doesn't work if greek letters are involved. The second answer says removing the space with `hspace{-0.1em}`. This works for a lot of letters but in some cases the Delta clashes with the variable. Furthermore, I don't know if ´0.1em` is the right amount of space to be removed, for me this choice seems rather arbitrary.

This MWE illustrates the problem at hand:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[slantedGreek,libertine]{newtxmath}

\newcommand{\updel}[1]{\upDelta\hspace{-0.1em}#1}
\newcommand{\sldel}[1]{\Delta\hspace{-0.1em}#1}

\begin{document}
Doesn't work:
\begin{equation}
  \mathit{\upDelta\Phi} \quad \mathit{\upDelta A}\text{.}
\end{equation}
Works only with \(\Phi\) but not with \(A\):
\begin{equation}
 \updel{\Phi} \quad \updel{A}\text{.}
\end{equation}
With slanted \(\Delta\):
\begin{equation}
 \sldel{\Phi} \quad \sldel{A}\text{.}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach would be to add spaces before and after `\upDelta x` but I couldn't say how much space is appropriate.

Comment: The spacing seems correct *and* necessary with `$\upDelta\Phi\upDelta A$`; why using `\mathit`?

Comment: In physical chemistry the uppercase delta is used to denote a change in an extensive quantity for a process (e.g. ΔH). The IUPAC Green Book (section 2.11.1 (iii) uses an upright symbol for those.

Comment: @egreg: I edited my question. I hope this makes it clear why the spacing can be problematic.

Comment: @cgnieder: Thank you, I added the IUPAP Red Book as a source. In physics the Delta is used in a similar way.

Comment: @frankundfrei in chemistry though it clearly is an operator (Δ = ∂/∂ξ) so it probably should get the same spacing as other operators. Interestingly enough the IUPAC Green book doesn't seem to care and uses the same spacing as for variables...

Comment: @cgnieder: In physics it is rather used as a kind of a finite differential. Often you have formulas that only really work for differentials d_f_, but as an approximation one can use "small" quantities Δ_f_. The Red Book lists it under Letter symbols and calls Δ a function. In that way it makes sense to use that spacing, but it still produces these (at least in my eyes) confusing looking equations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to remove the space between Δ and the following letter, but rather adding a thin space before it:

```
\newcommand{\updel}{\mathop{}\!\upDelta}
```

There is no “hidden multiplication” if the symbol is defined similarly to the differential.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[slantedGreek,libertine]{newtxmath}

\newcommand{\updel}{\mathop{}\!\upDelta}

\begin{document}
Here's an example
\begin{equation}
 x \updel\Phi + N \updel A.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks good! Could you please say a word or two about what `\mathop{}\!` does? `\!` is is a negative space but I don't understand what `\mathop{}` does and how you determined the size of the space (just because it looks OK, or is there a proper rule of how much space there should be?).

Comment: @frankundfrei You can read the explanation [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140647/4427)